# Getting the top padding of a scaled bitmap in an imageview that maintains aspect ratio

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, padding, scaling

I have a bitmap that is being rendered inside of an imageview.

The scaling is set so the bitmap maintains it's aspect ratio.  As such, there is padding on the top and bottom relative to the imageview.

What I'd like to do is get that padding.  I'm assuming this is possible no?

[image]

Comment: No answer? I'm facing this issue.